# How much weight can I put on this beam?

Tags: shower, beam

I have a beam that runs 18.5ft. The beam consisted of 2 2x10 and 1 1/2x10 steel plate. See photo for clarification. There is a shower bathroom on the edge of that beam. I am trying find out how much weight can that beam combination hold. Before the renovation, there was an acrylic tub in that space. I would like to build a walk in shower but am worried about the added weight of tile compared to an acrylic tub. I am hoping someone can help me better understand the weights that beam can hold.

[image: Layout from above]

[image: looking from floor under. The bathroom is marked in green on the right]

[image: Side view with the bathroom on the far side]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a Structural Engineer is required to safely and accurately make these calculations. Lives depend on this being accurate and it shouldn't be entrusted to well meaning random strangers on the internet.

Comment: I understand. I have a structural engineer scheduled to come out in a few days. I would still like to find an equation that can at least give me some numbers based on the wood beams and the metal plate present.

Answer (score 2):

Caveat: if you want a fully qualified answer, you really should go to a structural engineer. I'm not qualified as one. If I was, I would not be comfortable putting my name on this answer with the limited available information.

Thankfully you don't necessarily need this level of detail. If this structure previously served well for a tub, you should have no issue replacing the tub with a shower, even with added weight of tile or more acrylic. One of the key properties of a tub is that it fills with water and a person. Thirty gallons of water is about 240 pounds of weight. A shower doesn't hold near as much water, so if your new shower structure doesn't exceed the weight of the tub+water that was there before, you're good to go.

Comment: agree.  also this beam is picking up 1/2 the roof load and 1/2 of the load from the floor assembly and upper roof.  add some tile to that load is nothing.